# SQL doesn't get executed in production under Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, passenger

I have a code similar to the following:

```
class TheClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  connection.execute "set language 'us_english'"
  // the rest of the code
end
```

The execute command doesn't get executed in production under Passenger! Using Mongrel it's ok, putting the code inside a later called function works, Passenger+development settings also works.

Is there something different in the way Passenger deals with the connection or the Class instanciation that I'm not aware?

Edit:

It's clear that it's the way Passenger makes connections. So the question boils down to "Is there a **supported** way to execute a SQL statement when a connection is stablished?"

Comment: You really shouldn't call raw SQL, as it defies the agnosticism of ActiveRecord.

Comment: Except in this case this is clearly a database-specific command. IIRC there's some way to do it via the connection object, but you'd have to dig through a bunch of poorly documented AR innards.

Comment: I believe this is because class caching. Try turn off like `config.cache_classes = false` in `config/environments/production.rb` .  But this is not recommended to do in production anyway.

Comment: For why I need to do this see: https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/72

If I knew other way to set the language I'd use. Anyone?

The wonnage's answer fits well, because if it were class caching it would happen in mongrel too, right? It's Passenger's production environment specific.

Answer (score 1):

My psychic debugging says you're being bitten by Passenger's forking model.

Basically, Passenger forks a bunch of worker processes off a main process, which already has your rails environment loaded. This reduces the amount of time it takes the workers to initialize, since all your model, controller etc. classes are already there.

Now, from the Passenger documentation:

> Note that Phusion Passenger
>   automatically reestablishes the
>   connection to the database upon
>   creating a new worker process, which
>   is why you normally do not encounter
>   any database issues when using smart
>   spawning mode.

Your connection.execute statement runs when the TheClass is loaded. This actually only happens once, in the parent process that's forking all the workers. The workers each establish their own connections, but never run your 'set language' query since TheClass is already loaded. It works in dev mode because that reloads your classes every time.

There might be some sort of setup you can do in application.rb to tell ActiveRecord your connection language, otherwise you'll probably have to do an ugly hack of running that query in a before_filter or something.

Comment: The right way should be a callback in ActiveRecord like `after_connection` or the adapter set it up with a database.yml property.

Answer (score 0):

check your passenger error logs, these may be different from the standard rails log files.